# How can I redirect a request from consumer to my JS file to another folder

Tags: javascript

I have created a javascript plugin called "MyApp.js" and it is hosted in example.com/MyApp/ (example.com/MyApp/Scripts/MyApp.js).

I also chose to override the javascript file to refer from example.com/Publish/MyApp/MyApp.js using a boolean switch that I maintain in a config file in my web app.

Considering that MyApp.js is also consumed by several other consumers, and I wanted to redirect their requests to refer from example.com/Publish/MyApp/MyApp.js and not from example.com/MyApp/Scripts/MyApp.js.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Michal. I was able to achieve this using below:        <rule name="Redirect JS to another path in publish folder" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^Client/scripts/app/controllers/MyController.js" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="/Publish/SPRHub/MyController.js" />
        </rule>

Comment: Cheeeeeeerssssss :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear/>      
    <rule name="Redirect JS to another path in publish folder" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^Client/scripts/app/controllers/MyController.js" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/Publish/MyWebsite/MyController.js" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Added the above code in my web application web.config file. Launched the web application which had a reference to MyController.js file. Now the file gets redirected to the publish path given.